# How can I switch between pages with props in React

Tags: reactjs

I had it working initially, but I'm stuck on the homepage no matter what when I use this style

```
<Route
  to="/"
  render={(props) => <Home blogData={blogsData} {...props} />}
  exact
/>;
```

I initially had it set up like this

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

For reference, my whole route system is this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    to="/"
    render={(props) => <Home blogData={blogsData} {...props} />}
    exact
  />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
  <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
  <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
  <Route component={Error} />
</Switch>;
```

Any idea why I'm stuck on the homepage? The link will change correctly "/about", but it stays on the rendered homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Switch component will renders the first child  or  that matches the location.

`<Route path="/" />` also matches the url `"/about"`.
To solve this, you just need to add `exact={true}`

**Solution:**

`<Route path="/" exact render={.. } />`